# Creating Database and Assign user from PHP Code

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask about create user and database from PHP Code.

I have cpanel at server. At my application, I want my app create a database to backup something. But I always get error "access denied"

So, how to create a database and assign user to that database so this user can access it.

My code right now is:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","k3516438_disp","secret");
mysql_query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'k3516438_disp'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'secret' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS k3516438_dispatcher_backup",$con))
{
echo "Database created";
}
else
{
echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
}

mysql_select_db("universal_backup", $con);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE order_backup
(
order_id varchar(15),
request_id varchar(15)
)";

mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

And it still not works, that code I have write is from this: [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745675/create-mysql-user-and-database-from-php). But it doesn't work for me, I thought. Sorry for my Bad English.

Comment: Could you provide the exact error please?

Comment: Error creating database: Access denied for user 'k3516438_disp'@'localhost' to database 'k3516438_dispatcher_backup'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I backup it from local (my office), remote the database. Because at local there's no problem to that privileges. Thanks for all respond to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your user doesn't have relevant privileges.

Comment: well, that's my question. How to grant that user from PHP code.

Comment: If the user doesn't have access in the first place, it would be obviously unsecure if you could just request higher access via the user that needs it!  Create another user that your script will use, with the required permissions.  Then use that user inplace of the one you have. To create and grant subsequent users permission(s).

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to have the required privilege to user. He should have the privileges when he logged from a specific IP also. Please check whether user "k3516438_disp" have the privileges to create users and databases when accessing from your server IP.

May be your user "k3516438_disp" doesn't have the permission to access from "localhost". MySQL official site has more information about 'access denied' errors. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

Comment: I've give all privileges to that user.